# Subclass a widget to override method, while keeping original method functionality

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy data from QTableWidget. To do this I have sublclassed QTableWidget and overridden the keyPressEvent() method, which works well. However this looses useful keyPressEvent() functionality such as using direction keys to scroll through the table.

Is there a way to inherent the original method will implementing some additional functionality?

```
class SubQTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # inheret original keyPressEvent() functionality?
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
                event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy)):
            self.copy_selection()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override a method you have to understand if it conflicts with the new functionality. In this case the keyPressEvent method of QTableWidget does not conflict with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shorcut since they do nothing by default with that key so to avoid losing the previous functionality then you must call the parent's super method:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    super(SubQTableWidget, self).keyPressEvent(event)
    if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy)):
        self.copy_selection()
```

If you want to handle <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a simple way then you can use a QShortcut so there is no need to override the keyPressEvent method:

```
class SubQTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SubQTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy),
            self,
            activated=self.copy_selection,
            context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut
        )
```